# Likelihood ratio test question

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

If $X_i$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, are observations from the normal distribution with known variance $\sigma_i^2$, respectively, and $X_i$'s are mutually independent, construct a test for testing that their means are all equal.

My approach:
$\lambda=\frac{L(\omega)}{L(\Omega)}$
where $\omega$ comes from the space where all means are equal and hence in likelihood means are replaced  $\mu$ and $\sigma_i^2$ stay the same.
In, $L(\Omega)$, all means are staying as they were as $\mu_i$ and variances $\sigma_i^2$ .
Do, we need to replace means and variances by their maximum likelihood somewhere.
I am confused about that.

Comment: Yes, you want to replace the means by those that maximize the likelihood, (but not the variances as those are known). You use these means and variances to compute the $L(\omega)$ and $L(\Omega)$--that is where you replace them. Does that answer your question? If you want to learn more about your approach, read about the "likelihood ratio test." Your $-2\log(\lambda)$ is going to follow a $\chi_{n-1}$.

Comment: Can you please tell me, if we replace mu hat by xi or by x bar here, so all observations are different we should replace mu hat by xi.?

Comment: For $L(\omega)$, replace $\mu$ by $\bar{X}$ if the variances are the same--otherwise you need to do some reweighting. For $L(\Omega)$ replace all the $\mu_{i}$ by $X_{i}$.

Comment: Hey, can you please explain why do we replaced $\mu_i$ by $x_i$ in L($\Omega$)

Comment: @Proabability: I have written everything up formally now, let me know if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a likelihood ratio test, which gives the uniformly highest power by the Neyman-Pearson Lemma. The test statistic is computed as:

$$
T = -2 \left( \max_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}} l(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n} \ | \ \mu_1= \ldots = \mu_n = \mu) - \max_{\mu_{1}, \ldots, \mu_{n} \in \mathbb{R}} l(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n} \ | \ \mu_1, \ldots, \mu_{n}) \right) $$

Where $l(\cdot)$ is the log-likelihood function for a normal distribution:
$$l(X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n} \ | \ \mu_1, \ldots, \mu_{n}) = -\sum_{i} \frac{(X_{i}-\mu_{i})^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}_{i}} + (constant \ in \ \mu_{i}\text{'}s)$$
Which is clearly maximized by letting $\mu_{i} = X_{i}$, and the constants cancel across the two likelihoods.

Therefore:
$$T = \max_{\mu \in \mathbb{R}} \sum_{i} \frac{(X_{i}-\mu)^{2}}{ \sigma^{2}_{i}}$$
Differentiating with respect to $\mu$ gives the first order condition:
$$\sum_{i} \frac{-2(X_{i}-\mu^{*})}{ \sigma^{2}_{i}} = 0$$
$$\Longrightarrow \mu^{*} = \left( \sum_{i} \sigma_{i}^{-2} \right)^{-1}\left( \sum_{i} X_{i}\sigma_{i}^{-2} \right)$$
If all $\sigma^2_{i}$ are the same, then this simplifies to $\mu^{*} = \bar{X}$.

In conclusion, we can compute $\mu^{*}$ with the knowns $X_{i}$ and $\sigma^{2}_{i}$, and then the test statistic $T$:
$$T = \sum_{i}\frac{(X_{i}-\mu^{*})^{2}}{ \sigma^{2}_{i}}$$

By Wilk's theorem, the likelihood ratio test statistic in large samples follows a chi-squared with degrees of freedom equal to the difference in dimensionality between the null and alternative hypotheses, which in this case is $n-1$:
$$T \sim \chi^{2}_{n-1}$$
In our case, $\chi^{2}_{n-1}$ is actually the **exact** distribution of $T$, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3563361/find-the-distribution-of-xi).

The *p-value* can then be computed by taking $1$ minus the cdf of a $\chi^{2}_{n-1}$ evaluated at $T$.

Comment: Although you used a large sample approximation for the likelihood criterion, looks like the test based on $T$ is exact. Under $H_0$, distribution of $T$ is exactly $\chi^2_{n-1}$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3563361/321264).

Comment: @StubbornAtom: That's awesome, I have always been curious about that, thank you! I've added it to the solution accordingly.